# Memory is not released after function calls in python

Tags: python, pandas, memory, garbage-collection

I have been playing with `memory_profiler` for some time and got this interesting but confusing results from the small program below:

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

@profile
def f(p):
    tmp = []
    for _, frame in p.iteritems():
        tmp.append([list(record) for record in frame.to_records(index=False)])

# initialize a list of pandas panels
lp = []
for j in xrange(50):
    d = {}
    for i in xrange(50):
        df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(200, 50))
        d[i] = df
    lp.append(pd.Panel(d))

# execution (iteration)
for panel in lp:
    f(panel)
```

Then if I use memory_profiler's mprof to analyze the memory usage during runtime, `mprof run test.py` without any other parameters, I get this:
[image: memory_profiling_results_1.png].

There seems to be memory unreleased after each function call f().

`tmp` is just a local list and should be reassigned and memory reallocated each time f() is called. Obviously there is some discrepancy here in the graph attached. I know that python has its own memory management blocks and also has free list for int and other types, and `gc.collect()` should do the magic. It turns out that explicit `gc.collect()` doesn't work. (Maybe because we are working with pandas objects, panels and frames? I don't know.)

The most confusing part is, I don't change or modify any variable in `f()`. All it does is just put some list representation copies in a local list. Therefore python doesn't need to make a copy of anything. Then why and how does this happen?

=================

Some other observations:

1) If I call `f()` with `f(panel.copy())` (last line of code), passing the copy instead of the original object reference, I have a totally different memory usage result: [image: memory_profiling_results_2.png]. Is python that smart to tell that this value passed is a copy so that it could do some internal tricks to release the memory after each function call?

2) I think it might be because of `df.to_records()`. Well if I change it to `frame.values`, I would get similar flat memory curve, just like `memory_profiling_results_2.png` shown above, during the iteration (Although I do need `to_records()` because it maintains the column dtype, while `.values` messes the dtypes up). But I looked into frame.py's implementation on `to_records()`. I don't see why it would hold on the memory out there, while `.values` would work just fine.

I am running the program on Windows, with python 2.7.8, memory_profiler 0.43 and psutil 5.0.1.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch for pointing this out. An update on this: this is due to caching in pandas for dataframes. When `__getitem__()` is called for accessing columns of a dataframe, each column would be stored into `_item_cache`. And in this case it's because `pd.to_records()` has a list comprehension which includes `self[c] for ...` in it. All of the dataframe is in fact being cached after the call.

Comment: Any way to avoid the caching or work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a memory leak.  What you are seeing is a side effect of `pandas.core.NDFrame` caching some results.  This allows it to return the same information the second time you ask for it without running the calculations again.  Change the end of your sample code to look like the following code and run it.  You should find that the second time through the memory increase will not happen, and the execution time will be less.

```
import time

# execution (iteration)
start_time = time.time()
for panel in lp:
    f(panel)
print(time.time() - start_time)

print('-------------------------------------')
start_time = time.time()
for panel in lp:
    f(panel)
print(time.time() - start_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer first! Yeah I tried that too and was aware of the fact that it was not a leak! 
You said it was a side effect of the caching. Do you know where the caching happens? Or how? Because I did some similar experiments and it turned out that the caching did not happen every time. 
For example here if I use `.values` instead of `to_records()` I won't see the memory increasing. Could you point out to me where the caching is implemented in the pandas core? Or simply explain to me when the caching would come into our way?
Any way to work it around? Use `.copy()`?

Comment: The reason I need this to be "fixed" is that if I have a longer list and `lp` now consists of 500 objects, the memory would go up way too much.

Comment: With a debugger ( I use `pycharm`), you can step into the `pandas` code to see how it works.